# Как передать несколько глобальных переменных для всех view в Laravel 5.4 с помощю json и отловить их в ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel

Доброе время суток.

Есть вопрос: как с контролера создать переменную не, привязную к шаблону. То есть, у нас есть, скажем, 3 таблицы из базы:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $country = new Country();
        $city = new City;
        $items = Clients::orderby('id', 'ASC')->paginate(50);
        return response()->json($items);
    }
```

Одна из них выводиться через json. Как вывести все остальные в шаблон ?

Для большего понимания выложил часть кода вывода:

Контроллер:

```
public function manageItemAjax()
    {
        return view('manage-item-ajax');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Clients::orderby('id', 'ASC')->paginate(50);
        return response()->json($items);
    }
```

index.blade.php:

```
<table data-role="table" id="movie-table-custom" data-mode="reflow" class="movie-list table-stroke table table-bordered table-hover tblSearch" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Edit/Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{--Body of all clients--}}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

и наш js:

```
var page = 1;
var current_page = 1;
var total_page = 0;
var is_ajax_fire = 0;

manageData();

/* Manage data list */
function manageData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: {page: page}
    }).done(function (data) {

        total_page = data.last_page;
        current_page = data.current_page;

        jQuery('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: total_page,
            visiblePages: current_page,
            onPageClick: function (event, pageL) {
                page = pageL;
                if (is_ajax_fire != 0) {
                    getPageData();
                }
            }
        });

        manageRow(data.data);
        is_ajax_fire = 1;
    });
}

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

/* Get Page Data*/
function getPageData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: {page: page}
    }).done(function (data) {
        manageRow(data.data);
    });
}

/* Add new Item table row */
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';
    jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
        rows += '<tr class="clients' + value.id + '">' +
            '<td><b>ID: </b><span>' + value.id + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="firstnameAdd"><b>First Name: </b><span>' + value.firstname + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="lastnameAdd"><b>Last Name: </b><span>' + value.lastname + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="emailAdd"><b>Email: </b><span>' + value.email + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="addressAdd"><b>Address: </b><span>' + value.address + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="cityAdd"><b>City: </b><span>' + value.city + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="countryAdd"><b>Country: </b><span>' + value.country + '</span></td>' +
            '<td data-id="' + value.id + '">' +
            '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
            '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-item" class="btn btn-danger delete-item" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
    });
    jQuery("tbody").html(rows);
}
```

**Новое дополнение к вопросу:**

Хорошо с частью вопроса разобрался я вот теперь только ломаю голову с пару вопросами:

1. Какая ссылка должна быть в **url: url**, и почему здесь стоит именно такая запись ?
2. Как понять какое должно быть обозначения в **data** ? то когда я обозначаю в контроллере

   return response()->json([
               'city' => $city,
               'items' => $items
           ]);

и пытаюсь обозначить ее в jquery вот таким способом:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery(".like").html(data.items);
        }
    });
});
```

То ничего не выводиться, я что то потерял или что то не могу понять где моя ошибка(( Помогите(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открой App\Providers\AppServiceProvider и в методе boot() сделай что то вроде

```
view()->share('var', $var);
```

Comment: А как потом отловить событие в ajax если будет примеру несколько таких переменных?

Answer (score -1):

Создавай готовый html на сервере и отдавай на клиент:

Контроллер:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $country = new Country();
    $city = new City;
    $items = response()->json(Clients::orderby('id', 'ASC')->paginate(50));

    return response([
        'country' => $country,
        'city' => $city,
        'html' => view('parts._part', compact('items'))->render(),
    ]);
}
```

> Клиент получит 3 переменные: country, city и html - здесь уже готовый
>   html который нужно впихнуть в таблицу.

Создай views/parts/_part.blade.php:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<tr>
    <tr>{{ $item->id }}</tr>
    ...
</tr>
@endforeach
```

В js файле, в фунции manageRow() вместо этого кошмара просто:

```
/* Add new Item table row */
function manageRow(data) {
    jQuery("tbody").html(data);
}
```

Здесь:

```
/* Get Page Data*/
function getPageData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        data: {page: page}
    }).done(function (data) {
       // Здесь data.country, data.city, data.html
        manageRow(data.html);
    });
}
```

Comment: И данный вариант тоже, тут прикол в том что нельзя обозначать путь к шаблону, поскольку он тогда ломает структура ajax запроса.

Comment: И также после обновления ничего не работает, а есть просто вообще банальный возможно костыльный вариант передать значения без контроллера, и без route.php так сказать "кустарный метод".

Comment: Такой вопрос при попытке вызвать в **ajax**, **data.country** уже заранее установленным как в вашем примере то есть **'country' => $country** но он ничего не выводит, не подскажете почему ?

Comment: Конкретно в моем примере $country = new Country(); - просто создание экземпляра класса. А должно быть что-то вроде $country = Country::all(); - то есть получить список всех записей.

Comment: Ну тут немного так не получиться как ты написал поскольку это обращение к модулю а не к базе, и меня больше интересует как обозначить дату в json если туда передается много значений одновременно, посколько как я написал в примере когда я пытаюсь передавать data.data у меня просто пустая страница получается .